# pyglet: on_resize breaks graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I'm writing an application with pyglet where all rendered objects are children of the window class. I'm trying to draw a simple rectangle, but using on_resize seems to break everything. There's no error message, it just doesn't draw the rectangle.

This is my file structure:

```
main.py
lib
 |-- window.py
 |-- quad.py
```

This code doesn't work, but if I remove the on_resize methods it does:

```
-------------
FILE: main.py
-------------

import pyglet
import lib

window = lib.window.Window(1280, 720)

window.add_object(lib.quad.Quad())

pyglet.app.run()


-------------------
FILE: lib/window.py
-------------------

import pyglet

from . import quad

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        super().__init__(width=w, height=h)
        self.objects = []

    def on_draw(self):
        for obj in self.objects:
            obj.on_draw()

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        for obj in self.objects:
            obj.on_resize(width, height)

    def add_object(self, obj):
        self.objects.extend([obj])


-------------
FILE: lib/quad.py
-------------

import pyglet
import pyglet.gl

class Quad():
    def __init__(self):
        self.quad = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(4, ('v2i', (10, 10,  100, 10, 100, 100, 10, 100)), ('c3B', (0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0,  0, 255, 0)))

    def on_draw(self):
        self.quad.draw(pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS)

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        pass
```

I would like to be able to keep rendered objects as children of the window class, since that makes running event handlers much easier. Is there any way that I can make this work with the on_resize handler? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I tried removing on_resize from the Quad class, and making on_resize do nothing in the Window class. It seems like the existence of the on_resize function is the issue--if on_resize exists, pyglet wont draw the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the on_resize method add the glViewport function call. And also don't forget to set up an orthogonal projection. Take a look at my code, it draws a triangle at the center of the screen.

```
from pyglet.gl import *

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(3, ('v3f', [0,0,0, 300,0,0, 150,300,0]),
                                                       ('c3B', [255,0,0, 0,255,0, 0,0,255]))

    def draw(self):
        self.vertices.draw(GL_TRIANGLES)


class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(400, 300)
        glClearColor(0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 1.0)

        glOrtho(0, 1280, 0, 720, -10, 10) # setup orthogonal projection

        self.triangle = Triangle()

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslatef(640-150 ,360-150, 0) # translate the Triangle to the center
        self.triangle.draw()
        glPopMatrix()

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height) # resize the viewport


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyWindow(1280, 720, 'My window', resizable=True)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: This allows me to use on_draw and on_resize at the same time, but it seems like my color data is lost. No matter what I change the color on the quad to, it renders as blue. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Also, if you could explain the arguments passed to glOrtho(), that would be really useful.

Comment: Without seeing your code, i can not help. Upload it to github, and add a link here.
Arguments to glOrtho:
glOrtho(lowerLeft, width, lowerLeft, height, nearClippingPlane, farClippingPlane)

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong. I tried messing with glOrtho and glViewport to make it easier to do 2D rendering, and it messed everything up. Using transforms seems to be the secret to making everything work. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is by subclassing Window, (MyWindow in this case), when you define an on_resize() event handler, you are replacing the inherited handler with your own. What you want to do instead is to push your on_resize() handler onto the event handling stack so that both handlers get called.  You want to do the same some for of the others like on_close().  Example:

```
class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(400, 300)

        #
        # Push your handler onto the on_resize handler stack
        #
        self.push_handlers(on_resize=self.local_on_resize)

    def local_on_resize(self, x, y):
        # Do stuff

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.triangle.draw()
```

Note that you can reproduce the failure by having your local_on_resize() handler return a value of pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED, (which will stop processing of the remaining handlers), and the graphics won't render.